# Нужно всунуть переменную в ajax код даю

Tags: mysql

вывод

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_employees WHERE user_id = '$my_id' ORDER BY emp_id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_dept']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['emp_salary']; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <a id="<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>&user_id=<?=$my_id;?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>





        <td>


        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View</button>                       


        </td>

        <td>
```

аякс

```
/* Data Delete Starts Here */
$(".delete-link").click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var user_id = $(this).attr("user_id");
    var del_id = id;
    var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
    if(confirm('Вы собираетесь удалить обзор - id : = ' +del_id))
    {
        $.post('delete.php?user_id=<?=$my_id;?>', {'del_id':del_id, 'user_id':user_id}, function(data)
        {
            parent.fadeOut('slow');
        }); 
    }
    return false;
});
/* Data Delete Ends Here */
```

запрос

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($_POST['del_id'])
{
    $id = $_POST['del_id']; 
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_employees WHERE emp_id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));  
}
?>
<?

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/sql_social.php';



$kolvo = 30;



$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];


mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ballu_redactora=ballu_redactora-".$kolvo." WHERE id='".$user_id."'");


echo "<br>";
echo "Так как вы удалили обзор, у вас вычли $kolvo баллов!";
echo "<br>";
echo "У вас теперь баллов : $newbal ";
echo "$user_id";
```

Comment: если напрямую обратиться к файлу delete c переменной запрос проходит а когда удаляет через аякс нет(

Comment: а какие ошибки пишет консоль? а что вообще происходит? а почему отправляешь POST запрос, а даешь GET параметры `?user_id=`?

Comment: ну блин гет потому что думал что получится дописать адрес с переменной а не пошло ошибок нет просто мне надо чтоб списывал 30 баллов

Comment: у меня не получается подставить значение переменной my_id правильно